# How to improve magento 2 site performance

Tags: magento-2.1, optimization

I started working on magento 2 these days.

In  magento 1.9 i used full page cache to optimize the site a bit and follows GTMETRIX reports.

But in Magento 2 i am new can any one used such methods to speed up the Magento 2 store efficiently. Or is there any in built functionality that comes in Magento 2